# departir and "I let you know"/"I will let you know"

Tags: traducción, verbos

I'm searching for a verb for the phrase "let you know", i.e. informal dialogue.

Is the infinitive "departir" similar? Wordreference.com struggles to identify its meaning, is it rarely used? One translation is it means "to mingle with", i.e. socialise. I understand the difference from "compartir", to share voluntarily versus to distribute something.

I would like to know what "departir"  it means in the context of dialogue and is their verb for "let you know"?

Comment: No, *departir* es muy formal y antiguo, así que rara vez lo vas a escuchar en una conversación

Comment: Muchas gracias @tar, ahora entendido.

Comment: Con permiso, edito el título para que sea más claro lo que estás preguntando

Comment: Por supuesto, no problema @tac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a colloquial and not so formal context, in the middle of a conversation, there are several ways to interrupt to make an addition to what is being said noticed:

> Hoy es 21 de septiembre y **te hago saber** que comienza el otoño

> Hoy es 21 de septiembre y **también te digo** que comienza el otoño

> Mañana hará calor **aunque te digo** que lloverá

> Mañana hará calor **aunque te advierto** que lloverá

> Mañana hará calor y **te comunico** que lloverá

> Mañana hará calor y **te cuento** que lloverá

Comment: Ah of course "contar", I did know that and slipped my mind. Thanks this is comprehensive, much appreciated.

Comment: *Make an addition to what is being said* no necesariamente implica *to interrupt* la conversation.

Comment: Además, se responde parcialmente a lo preguntado ya que en ningún momento se ofrece una traducción para *will let you know*, construcción usada para referir a incertezas futuras. Siendo éste el uso más común de *let you know* (referir al futuro con un grado considerable de incerteza), paradójicamente la otra respuesta es más completa. No puedo creer que sea ésta la respuesta aceptada.

Answer (score 4):

No, [departir](https://dle.rae.es/departir?m=form) does not have this meaning and is not really used much anymore.

To say "I will let you know" I usually say "Te aviso" or "Te avisaré". [**Avisar**](https://dle.rae.es/avisar?m=form) (see first meaning) means precisely "let someone know of a new fact or event". In a more formal context, you might use "informar" instead.

Comment: Thank you, upvoted, the definition is exactly what I'm looking for but its beyond my current level of Spanish. I need to study this verb.